# Read Replicas with multiple instances of MySQL running on different ports

Tags: mysql, replication

I have a specific need to create a single linux server which can host 4 MySQL instances with read replication. Here are a few questions I cannot seem to find answers to:

1. Can you setup read replication through MySQL similar to Amazon RDS, or is
   Amazon using a propriety application to handle this read/write
   replication? If not, are there standalone packages for this kind of replication?
2. Can you set individual settings for each MySQL installation? For instance I want a memory limit for MySQL running on port 64506 of 2GB, but MySQL installation on port 3306 should have a 16GB memory limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, Amazon uses standard replication for its instances. Not only [it is documented here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html), but also is proven with the fact that you can replicate from and to MySQL instances outside of RDS. No need for any extra packages/software, a standard MySQL server can be a master and/or a slave with the appropriate configuration and preparation.
2. Yes, if you [run several MySQL instances on the same node](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/multiple-servers.html) (assuming you have changed its port, data directory, pid and socket), you can configure them with different buffer sizes, max_connections, etc. However, make sure to understand that there is no way to hard limit the maximum memory or CPU usage on MySQL configuration - if you want real isolation, you have to go to virtualization or other operating system limits (this is what Amazon actually does).

I recommend you to have a look at [MySQL Sandbox](http://mysqlsandbox.net/), which makes easier to setup MySQL and replication among them on the same machine.

Comment: I understand that MySQL has replication out of the box, but I want a write/read master/slave situation where all of the reads will come from slave, and all of the writes will go to master. I can't find documentation on this functionality save for stuff about Amazon RDS (same link you mentioned). Thank you for other information!

Comment: @David Allen Doing read/write split is very easy, depending on your stack/programming language I can provide you with specific examples (PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-ms.rwsplit.php Java: http://blog.yannickjaquier.com/mysql/connectorj-with-mysql-replication.html Rails: https://github.com/taskrabbit/makara). The problem is that many times, the results are wrong if handled fully-automatically because application should be replication-aware.

Comment: So it appears that this is an application level feature, and not something MySQL will handle. Thanks!

Comment: @David Allen Well, it can be done at middleware level (MySQL Proxy), but usually it is done at least at connector/pool level.